# KryoNet: Client disconnects immediately after connecting

Tags: java, networking, kryo, kryonet

This seems to be a popular problem, but I'm still having trouble finding a solution even after spending a lot of time troubleshooting.  I'm hoping there's an updated solution.

I'm setting up a simple Server and Client with the KryoNet Java networking library.  My problem is that my client disconnects immediately after connecting to the server.

Here is my code:

**Server**

```
public class TheServer extends Listener {

    static Server server;
    static final int PORT = 8215;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        server = new Server();
        server.start();
        server.bind(PORT);
        server.addListener(new TheServer());
        System.out.println("server started on " + PORT);
    }

    public void connected(Connection c) {
        System.out.println("connected: " + c.getID());
    }

    public void disconnected(Connection c) {
        System.out.println("disconnected: " + c.getID());
    }

}
```

**Client**

```
public class TheClient extends Listener {

    static Client client;
    static final String IP = "localhost";
    static final int PORT = 8215;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        client = new Client();
        client.start();
        client.connect(5000, IP, PORT);
        client.addListener(new TheClient());
        //client.setKeepAliveTCP(2000);
    }

}
```

After running `TheServer` and then `TheClient`, my console prints:

```
server started on 8215
connected: 1
disconnected: 1
```

Note that the time between the connection and disconnection is almost immediate, certainly less than the connection timeout time I set. Also note that I commented out the `setKeepAliveTCP()` method because while I do not think it is necessary, I inserted it to see if it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more [digging around](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kryonet-users/QTHiVmqljgE), I found that starting the client with:

`new Thread(client).start()`

instead of

`client.start()`

fixes the problem.

> "Starting with r122, client update threads were made into daemon threads, causing the child processes to close as soon as they finish initializing."

Comment: Sometimes this doesn't work aswell.. then all your registerred classes should have an empty constructor in them, https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet/issues/35